# Count en consulta sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de contar la cantidad de ubicaciones `(SELECT COUNT(t.SI_Ubicacion)) AS cantidad,`

```
SELECT 
t.SI_Articulo, 
m.SI_Descripcion, 
t.SI_UM, 
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END) AS SI_OV, 
(SELECT COUNT(t.SI_Ubicacion)) AS cantidad, 
t.SI_Existencia, c.SI_Cantidad, c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia AS SI_Dif ,
(c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia) * m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif_Dinero 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo 
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
```

Pero me dice que:

> La columna 'SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD.SI_Articulo' de la lista de
>   selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de
>   agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: Como te indica el error, cuando haces una consulta con un count,  los demás campos incluidos en una consulta deben ir agrupados, porque por su condición no podría hacerse la cuenta. Se soluciona simplemente añadiendo el GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo al final. Probablemente tengas que añadir más group by en tu consulta también.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias agrupar en la clausula group by las columnas que no estan incluidas en una funcion de agregacion como lo es count

```
SELECT 
t.SI_Articulo, 
m.SI_Descripcion, 
t.SI_UM, 
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END) AS SI_OV, 
(SELECT COUNT(t.SI_Ubicacion)) AS cantidad, 
t.SI_Existencia, c.SI_Cantidad, c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia AS SI_Dif ,
(c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia) * m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif_Dinero 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON 
m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo 
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo,m.SI_Descripcion,t.SI_UM,SI_OV,t.SI_Existencia, c.SI_Cantidad, SI_Dif ,SI_Dif_Dinero
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que uses count en SELECT para mostrar los datos que necesitas, tods los otros datos necesitan estar agrupados segun algo, necesitas poner un group by al final de toda tu consulta

Podrias probar poner al final

```
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo, m.SI_Descripcion, t.SI_UM, t.SI_Existencia, c.SI_Cantidad
```

Otra observacion, estas manejando muchas condiciones en el SELECT, movelas a un WHERE mejor